# Capturing Image with Tablet Camera and Saving it C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I am building a WPF app that will be used on Windows tablets. My organization would like a way to take a picture with the tablet, and somehow submit this along with a "report" which is housed in a database. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to even begin. I have done research, but yet to have obtained a clear answer. It seems there are classes that can be used to interact with a WebCam, but I am not sure how (and if) this would work with a tablet camera.

I need to allow the user to  to take an image, and somehow associate it with the report, (perhaps uploading it to a server and then saving a reference to it in a field) all without leaving the application.

I am certainly not expecting anyone to write my application for me, but I am not quite sure if this is possible or how to begin, as such, I would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps this is stupid question, but since I do not currently have a tablet to test it on, I must ask: when it comes to accessing and manipulation, is a webcam treated the same way as a tablet's hardware camera? That latter is what I need to access, but pretty much every resource points to webcams. Thanks again.